# Disable blue screen on shutdown

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am having a Raspbmc image on my Raspberry Pi. To meet one of the requirements I need to restart xbmc. When I restart xbmc is displays screens of various colors. I do not want these different colors. I want a completely black screen. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try issuing `<splash>false</splash>` per the following under the heading "Splash Screen:
http://cybernetnews.com/xbmc-advanced-settings/